# How to set row number()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this -

```
C1   C2         C3
A   20130101    10
A   20130102    10
A   20130103    20
A   20130104    10
```

I want to set row no like this -

```
C1   C2         C3   RowNo
A   20130101    10   1
A   20130102    10   2
A   20130103    20   1
A   20130104    10   1
```

How can I make by query?
or there is only way to loop this table?

Thanks..

Comment: What is your RowNo based on, C3 and C2 in a way? Please explain how you get to those RowNos

Comment: I want to set row no like this,
- Accending by date
- Row no will increase until value of C3 is not change.
- When value of C3 is change, Row no will be restart form 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updated answer with recursive CTE. It build hierarchy tree starting with records with new C3's value and  display level as RowNo.

```
with t as 
(select t.*, row_number () over (order by c2) rn from table1 t)

,temp (c2,c3,rn,lvl)  AS 
(SELECT c2,c3,rn,1 lvl from t t1  
                       where not exists(
                                        select 1 from t t0 
                                                 where t1.rn=t0.rn+1 
                                                   and t1.c3=t0.c3
                                       )
  UNION ALL 
 select t1.c2,t1.c3,t1.rn,lvl + 1 AS lvl FROM t t1
 join temp t2 on t1.rn=t2.rn+1 and t1.c3=t2.c3)

SELECT c2, c3, lvl rowno FROM temp order by rn;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4adbd/1

Comment: this is what I want to do. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

ROW_NUMBER() function can help you to set numbers of rows:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [some field]), *
      FROM [your table]
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY [C3] order by [C2]), *
      FROM  table name